# How many fish are there on Floor 14?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

I'm doing the Fishing Tournament quest and am attempting to catch all the fish. I have five fish marked on my map, and have caught all of them. The message I received upon catching the fifth fish suggests that there are more than five fish though.

How many fish can I catch on Floor 14, and what are their locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nine fishing spots on B14. I have included a not-so-awesome photo of my map on that level. They are at the exclamation points.

Assuming a coordinate system that uses the letter and number to get a 5x5 sub-grid, and the coordinates that are how many down and how many right, the positions are:

- A3(4,5)
- A5(4,4)
- B2(3,4)
- D1(3,2)
- D5(2,3)
- E2(3,1)
- E5(2,5)
- F5(3,3)
- F7(4,3)

[image]

Note that while collecting fish, you *can* use the floor jump to get around more easily without it counting as leaving the level.